# How to access a struct element when the struct is inside mapping

Tags: solidity

```
struct adminMember{
        address admin;
        bool _isDeleted;
    }
    mapping(address => adminMember) adminMembers;
```

I want to access  _isDeleted value and return it from a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you create this function which returns a `bool` value

```
function myFunction(address admin) external view returns (bool) {
   return adminMembers[address]._isDeleted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for access.

```
adminMembers[adminAddress]._isDeleted
```

Function.

```
function isDeleted(address adminAddress) external view returns (bool) {
       return adminMembers[adminAddress]._isDeleted;
}
```